# Will I damage a text file by binary copying it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, python-3.4

I want to copy a tree of files/directories (recursively, of course) that have bad characters in the file names. So, I'm opening the file, reading its contents, and dumping them into a new file with a cleaned name.

If the contents of a file are text, and I read() them into write() while in binary mode, is there any chance of that damaging the contents?

```
for name in os.listdir(src_path):
    name = clean_name(name)
    src_full = os.sep.join((src_path, name))
    dst_full = os.sep.join((dst_path, name))
    ...
    if isfile(src_full):
        with open(dst_full, 'xb'): as dst_file:
            with open(src_full, 'rb')) as src_file:
               dst_file.write(src_file.read())
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why it would.

Comment: What are "bad characters"?

Comment: Text files are binary files which just happen to use the bytes in a way that maps to a text encoding. So you can treat any text file as binary without a problem, you just don’t get the “extra” that you are able to get the text for free (you would have to do the decoding yourself—which also isn’t hard).

Comment: @Tichodroma For one, the pipe character.. which TSX probably put in the title of their webpage to make it more annoying to scrape lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no chance of damaging the contents. You'll be reading the exact contents as they are, bit for bit, insofar your hardware can provide you with the accurate contents.

What *can* happen is that you forget to copy across all the file *metadata*; access control information and modification and creation dates are lost, for example.

Rather than read the whole file into memory, use the [`shutil.copyfile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to handle the file copy for you; it'll copy data across in blocks. Better still, use the [`shutil.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) or [`shutil.copy2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) functions and it'll copy across permissions too; `copy2()` also copies file access and creation times.

All three functions open the file in binary mode; the source is opened with `'rb'`, the destination with `'wb'`. If you *must* have exclusive opening (mode `'xb'`), you'll need to open the file objects yourself (as you already do) and use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to get the efficient file copy, followed either by a [`shutil.copymode()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copymode) (to replicate `shutil.copy()` and copy file permissions) or a [`shutil.copystat()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copystat) (to replicate what `shutil.copy2()` does).